# Modeling the spread of an infection in networked computers

Tags: function-construction, simulation, iterators

I would like to show the iterative stages of infection for problem 2 in [this link](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2017/mar/13/can-you-solve-it-pi-day-puzzles-that-will-leave-you-pie-eyed).

In case the link dies, I have copied the text for the problem below:

> One hundred computers are connected in a 10x10 network grid, as below. At the start exactly nine of them are infected with a virus. The virus spreads like this: if any computer is directly connected to at least 2 infected neighbours, it will also become infected.

[image]

It is fairly straightforward to show the first stage of infection (blue):

```
Module[{a, b, c, d, e, x, y, z},

x = 6; y = 5;
z = Array[{#, #2} &, {y, y}];
a = Flatten[z, 1];
b = RandomSample[a, x];
c = Complement[a, b];
d = Select[
    Thread@{c, Thread@Table[EuclideanDistance[b[[t]], #] & /@ c, {t, x}]}, 
    Count[#[[2]], 1] > 1 &][[All, 1]];
e = Complement[a, Join[b, d]];

Graphics[{Line /@ Join[z, Thread@z], PointSize[.05], 
Point /@ e, Red, Point /@ b, Blue, Point /@ d}]

]
```

[image]

I would like to show (via manipulate or otherwise) each stage of infection until the maximum number for that particular seed has been infected. I have had a play with `NestWhileList`, but coming up short at present.

Comment: Suggest you post your solution as a self-answer, rather than as an update to your question. That would be more in accordance with the norms of this site.

Comment: @m_goldberg ok, done :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If it is at all an option to represent the grid as a 2D list instead of a list of infected coordinates, I would model this is a cellular automaton. What you've essentially got is an [outer totalistic cellular automaton](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Outer-TotalisticCellularAutomaton.html) with a [von Neumann neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood). The rule in [Game-of-Life notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life-like_cellular_automaton#Notation_for_rules) is B234/S01234, i.e. a cell comes to life if it has two or more live neighbours and it always survives. Implementing simple CAs is quite straight-forward with Mathematica's [`CellularAutomaton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellularAutomaton.html), and I've written [another answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111569/2305) about how to figure out the rule number of the CA.

For your case, we're using the weights:

```
{{0, 2, 0}, 
 {2, 1, 2}, 
 {0, 2, 0}}
```

And then the rule turns out to be `1018`. So we can simulate a single step with the following function:

```
CellularAutomaton[
  {
    1018, 
    {2, {{0, 2, 0}, {2, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 0}}}, {1, 1}
  }, 
  {#, 0}
][[1, 2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]] &
```

The indexing at the end is used to remove the background information returned by `CellularAutomaton`.

However, **as of version 11.1** specifying common CA rules has become a lot more convenient. The possibility to specify a CA rule via an association allows for rather high-level classifications. In fact, Mathematica now knows about various neighbourhoods:

```
CellularAutomaton[<|
    "OuterTotalisticCode" -> 1018, 
    "Neighborhood" -> "VonNeumann", 
  |>, 
  {#, 0}
][[1, 2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]] &
```

And we don't even need to compute that rule code, because we can specify the rule directly via a set of growth cases:

```
CellularAutomaton[<|
    "GrowthCases" -> {2, 3, 4}, 
    "Neighborhood" -> "VonNeumann", 
  |>, 
  {#, 0}
][[1, 2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]] &
```

This says "when a dead cell has 2, 3 or 4 live neighbours, the cell comes alive", which is exactly what we're looking for.

To simulate the infection to convergence, I'd recommend [`FixedPointList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html) instead of [`NestWhileList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html). It simply applies a function over and over until the value stops changing, and then gives you all the intermediate values.

```
Module[{a, b, d = 25},
  a = RandomChoice[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {d, d}];
  b = Most @ FixedPointList[
    CellularAutomaton[<|
        "GrowthCases" -> {2, 3, 4}, 
        "Neighborhood" -> "VonNeumann", 
      |>, 
      {#, 0}
    ][[1, 2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]] &, a];
  ListAnimate[ArrayPlot /@ b]
]
```

[image]

Adding some information about the history is as easy as calling [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) on the list of grids before handing them to `ArrayPlot`, which now colours each cell by its relative age:

[image]

To show the absolute age instead of the relative age, you can give `ArrayPlot` the option `PlotRange -> {0, Length@b}`:

[image]

Comment: thank you for this fantastic answer! Had not thought of going down the cellular automaton route - shading cells by relative age is exactly what I was after - many thanks again!

Comment: With the new Mathematica 11.1 there is now a more intuitive way of specifying the CA rule. I'll update the answer once my licence upgrades and I can actually play around with the new rule specifications.

Comment: great - look forward to it :)

Comment: @martin Took a few days. Done.

Comment: Despite the competing answer I just posted I find yours excellent and you have my vote, FWIW.

Comment: @MartinEnder brilliant:)

Answer (score 12):

Non `CellularAutomaton` solution, using @MartinEnder's suggestion of `FixedPointList` as opposed to `NestWhileList`:

```
f[initial_List, infected_List, rest_List] := 
  With[{newinfected = Join[infected, Select[Thread@{rest, 
  Thread@Table[EuclideanDistance[infected[[t]], #] & /@ rest, 
  {t, Length@infected}]}, Count[#[[2]], 1] > 1 &][[All, 1]]]}, 
  {initial, newinfected, Complement[initial, newinfected]}];

z = Array[{#, #2} &, {10, 10}]; a = Flatten[z, 1];
b = {{1, 1}, {1, 10}, {3, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 7}, {5, 8}, {7, 5}, {7, 10}, {9, 9}, {10, 4}};
c = Complement[a, b];

With[{e = FixedPointList[f[#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]] &, {a, b, c}]}, 
Manipulate[Graphics[{Thickness[.01], Line /@ Join[z, Thread@z], PointSize[.05], 
RGBColor[0, .5, 1], Point /@ e[[w, 3]], RGBColor[1, .5, 0], 
Point /@ e[[w, 2]]}], {w, 1, Length@e, 1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @AnjanKumar no, it won't for 9 on a 10*10 grid. There are solutions for 10 on a 10*10 grid though - like the one above.

Answer (score 7):

The demonstration of `CellularAutomaton` is impressive but it is far from necessary for this problem.  I propose [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate.html) instead. Keeping much of Martin Ender's code for ease of comparison:

```
d = 25;

a = RandomChoice[{7, 1} -> {0, 1}, {d, d}];

ker = {{0, 1, 0},
       {1, 2, 1},
       {0, 1, 0}};

fn = UnitStep[ListCorrelate[ker, #, 2, 0] - 2] &;

ArrayPlot /@ FixedPointList[fn, a] // ListAnimate
```

[image]

In addition to being simpler (in my opinion) `ListCorrelate` is somewhat faster:

```
ender = CellularAutomaton[{1018, {2, {{0, 2, 0}, {2, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 0}}}, {1, 
       1}}, {#, 0}][[1, 2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]] &;

big = RandomChoice[{20, 1} -> {0, 1}, {1000, 1000}];

Nest[ender, big, 10] // RepeatedTiming // First
Nest[fn, big, 10]    // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.606
>
> 0.363
> ```

(In *Mathematica* 10.1 I cannot test the newer syntax shown.)

Comment: great addition-thanks :)

Comment: I accidentally find this post and the first thing came to my mind is `ListCorrelate`. I was eagerly scrolling down and trying to post an answer when I found that you've got there first...... Good post still~

Comment: @Wjx Sorry?  And thank you.